# Query on Guillotine press

Tags: upper-body-workout, bench-press, chest

I have been doing the guillotine press for two weeks due to the unavailability of an incline bench at my gym. I heard that it can cause serious rotator cuff injury when used long term. I wanted to know the method to perform this exercise safely and some rotator cuff exercises that can help mitigate rotator cuff injuries caused by guillotine press.

Comment: Do you currently have rotator cuff issues?

Comment: I never had a rotator cuff injury. Four years back I had an anterior shoulder dislocation. That's the only injury I had in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to assume that any exercise invented by the bodybuilder Vince Gironda is just risking one's joint health in futility, many people got injured because of the  ignorance spread by that guy, he literally took normal exercises and transformed them into joint destroying ones.